# Is there a way to match the first n characters in an elixir string

Tags: elixir

How can you match the first n characters from a string? Something like:

```
def take(n) do
  head :: size(n) <> rest = "my string"
end
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get the first `n` *bytes* using pattern matching:

```
iex(1)> n = 4
4
iex(2)> <<head :: binary-size(n)>> <> rest = "my string"
"my string"
iex(3)> head
"my s"
iex(4)> rest
"tring"
```

You cannot get the first `n` UTF-8 codepoints using a single pattern since UTF-8 characters can occupy a variable number of bytes and pattern matching in Elixir does not support that. You can get the first (or a fixed number of) UTF-8 codepoints using `::utf8` in the pattern:

```
iex(1)> <<cp::utf8>> <> rest = "ƒoo"
"ƒoo"
iex(2)> cp
402
iex(3)> <<cp::utf8>>
"ƒ"
iex(4)> rest
"oo"
```